# Flutter&Firebase - Got issues with Firebase storage when modifying profil picture

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I need help with a flutter application linked with Firebase. This application has a login method and I want to have a picture where users can update it whenever they want.

For now, I manage to replace a picture who's already existing in a Firebase Storage's file by a picture taken from the gallery of a phone (*uploadFile*). Also I can take back this picture from Firebase Storage if it's already existing in Firebase Storage (*getProfilImage*).

**The issue:**
However, when I want to add a new picture from my application to the Firebase Storage, Firebase doesn't allow my user to create a new file with the new picture and my app crashed.

If someone could give me a help in order to change the picture of the user without already having a file for this picture in Firebase Storage, I would appreciate

**The debug console error**

```
E/StorageException(17322): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(17322): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(17322):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(17322): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException(17322): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
```

**The function to upload an image to Firebase Storage:**
NB: The code works when $currentUser is replaced by an already existing file

```
 Future uploadFile() async {
    Reference storageRef = storage.ref().child('UsersImageProfil/$currentUser.png'); 
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(imageProfilFile!);
    await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {
       print('File uploaded');  
      setState(() {
              imageProfilFile = null;
            });  
    });
  }
```

**The function to get the image from Firebase Storage**
NB: The code works when $currentUser is replaced by an already existing file

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getProfilImage();
  }

   getProfilImage() {
    Reference ref = storage.ref().child('UsersImageProfil/$currentUser.png');
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
      setState(() {
        userPhotoUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      setState(() {
        userPhotoUrl = defaultImageUrl;
      });
      print('Une erreur est survenue: ${e.error}');
    });
  }
```

**The function who display the picture**

```
class SetPhotoProfilState extends State<SetPhotoProfil> {
  File? imageProfilFile;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  String? userPhotoUrl;
  String defaultImageUrl = 'https://svgsilh.com/png-1024/2098873.png';
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(kColorPrimary)),
            onPressed: () async {
              Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
                Permission.storage,
                Permission.camera,
              ].request();
              if (statuses[Permission.storage]!.isGranted &&
                  statuses[Permission.camera]!.isGranted) {
                showImagePicker(context);
              } else {
                print('No permission');
              }
            },
            child: Text("Modifier sa photo de profil")),
        userPhotoUrl == null
            ? CircleAvatar(
                radius: 42,
                backgroundColor: kColorPrimary,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 40,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                   defaultImageUrl, // Remplacez l'URL par le lien de votre image de profil
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : CircleAvatar(
                radius: 42,
                backgroundColor: kColorPrimary,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40, backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userPhotoUrl!)),
              ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

**The showImagePicker function**

```
  void showImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return Card(
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5.2,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.image, size: 60.0),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 12.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Gallerie',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        _imgFromGallery();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),

   _imgFromGallery() async {
     await picker
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50)
        .then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        imageCache.clear();
      setState(() {
        imageProfilFile = File(croppedFile.path);
        convertImageToPNG();
        uploadFile(); 
      });
      }
    });
  }
```

**Also** I've already modify the Storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. It seems that the error came from the `getProfilImage()` function. There is the new `getProfilImage()` function:

```
Future getProfilImage() async {
var urlRef = storage.ref().child("UsersImageProfil").child("${currentUser.uid}");
  if (urlRef == null) {
    setState(() {
userPhotoUrl = null;
    });
  }
  try{
var imgURL = await urlRef.getDownloadURL();
 setState(() {
      userPhotoUrl = imgURL;
    });
  } catch(error) {
    print("erreur getProfilImage");
  }
}
```

I just had to put an if condition in order to help firebase storage to manage the case if there wasn't any picture yet in the storage. I also change the `UploadFile` function:

```
Future uploadFile() async {
  Reference referenceRoot = storage.ref();
  Reference referenceDirImages = referenceRoot.child('UsersImageProfil');
  Reference referenceImageToUpload =
    referenceDirImages.child('${currentUser.uid}');
  try {
    await referenceImageToUpload.putFile(imageProfilFile!);
    referenceImageToUpload.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userPhotoUrl = value;
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    print('erreur uploadFile');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***try updating yours with this rule***

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null; // Allow authenticated users to read and write files
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Allow files smaller than 10 MB to be created
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The debug console return the same issue even if I allow users to create in the Storage rules console.